# How can I pass sub-report value to main-report?

Tags: jasper-reports

**Here's the relation table**

```
StudentName
Course
Marks



Peter
Bio
65

Peter
Chem
70



Peter
Music
80



David
Chem
50
```

**How can I make something like the followings**

```
Peter            Total : 215

Subject : Bio    -   65
Subject : Chem   -   70
Subject : Music  -   80

Peter            Total : 50

Subject : Chem   -   50
```

Comment: Please don't place tag info in the subject line. The tag system is designed to properly place questions into categories, and it works extremely well to do so. It even sets things up properly to find things via Google without assistance. :-) Thanks. (Also, I think your second `Total` item should be "David", shouldn't it?)

Comment: i recommend to change the title - as nothing in your question indicates subreports usage. also, subreports would be overkill to achieve this. See answer below :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not use a subreport for this as this can be achieved in a simpler way: You can utilize Report groups and variables to achieve this. Make sure that the data is sorted accordingly to the output.

**Preparation**

- Create a report group based on *StudentName*. Right Click in iReport in the report inspector  on the report and select *Add Report group*. Follow the wizard, give it a name (e.g. `Student`), select field `StudentName` as group expression, add header but no footer.
- Create a variable that holds the total for a student. Right Click in iReport in the report inspector on *Variables* and select *Add Variable*. In the properties panel configure as follows: Name: totalMarkByStudent, Variable Class: java.lang.Long, Calculation: Sum, Reset Type: Group, Reset Group: Student, Variable Expression: $F{Marks}. Leave the rest to its default values.

**Report Design**

- Drag and drop the Field `StudentName` from the report inspector into the report designer into the Student group header band. There will be a popup asking what kind of value shall be displayed, select *The field value* and click Ok.
- Drag and drop the Variable `totalMarksByStudent`  from the report inspector into the report designer into the Student group header band. Click on the text field and modify following settings in the properties panel:

  - *Width*: `200` (to allow more space)
  - *Text field expression*: `"Total : " + $V{totalMarkByStudent}`
  - *Expression Class*: `java.lang.String`
  - *Evaluation Time*: `Group` (meaning that the value gets evaluated once the processing of the group is finished)
  - *Evaluation Group*: `Student`
- Drag and drop the fields *Course* and *Marks* from the report inspector into the detail band in the report designer. Right click on the course field and select *Edit Expression*. CHange the expression to `"Subject : " +  $F{Course}` and click on Apply.

With this configuration you achieve a report output as in the image below.
[image: report output]

For further reference here the complete JRXML using report group and variable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report3" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0dfbb9b2-a9ce-4447-beee-37d653140dd1">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from (
Select 'Peter' as StudentName, 'Bio' as Course, 65 as Marks
union select 'Peter', 'Chem', 70
union select 'Peter', 'Music', 80
union select 'David', 'Chem', 50
) tbl

order by StudentName, Course]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="StudentName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Course" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Marks" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <variable name="totalMarkByStudent" class="java.lang.Long" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Student" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Marks}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="Student">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{StudentName}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="50">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="ea996b6c-d41d-47bb-bef1-5df580b5c161" x="0" y="30" width="100" height="20"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{StudentName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="Student">
                    <reportElement uuid="8ddc9b5b-9c57-4fce-8ed0-587c6b54143c" x="180" y="30" width="200" height="20"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Total : " + $V{totalMarkByStudent}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <detail>
        <band height="20">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="f67b4e51-4da6-4758-b3d3-bd75de70c0f7" x="0" y="0" width="180" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Subject : " +  $F{Course}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="ea82c278-d2f3-4467-bf5d-8dab9ff99ae3" x="180" y="0" width="277" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Marks}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**If you use a subreport instead**

I assume that the subreport is paraemterized with the student id shows the data for a given student. The main report shows the field `StudentName` and the subreport in the detail panel.

- Create a variable `total` in the subreport that calculates the total for the student.
- Create a variable `totalByStudent` in the main report with calculation type set to `System`.
- Click on the subreport and in the properties panel click on Return values. Click Add and select: Subreport variable:  total, Local Destination Variable: totalByStudent, rest leave to default. Click on Ok.
- Drag and drop the variable `totalByStudent` into the detail band. Select it and in the Properties panel set Evaluation time to *Band*. The output will be the same as shown above.

I recommend to use the approach with report group and variable as it reduces the complexity of the report, as well as performance for this way would be better.

Comment: There's no "Return values" in the properties panel of the subreport.