# return value from sub report to main report

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have googled and prepared my sample report as per the given steps.

Steps:

1. Create sub report with variable retval_sub [kept default value to the variable as Hai]
2. Create main report variable retval_main.
3. Sub report properties --> added sub report variable as retval_sub and corresponding main report variable is retval_main.

I tried many times but it is not working i kept calculation type as System and Nothing also but it is not working for both.

Main report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="testing_ret_val" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="5c1d1561-8eed-47a8-89c8-3cd1946ce07a">
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["E:\\ilaiyaraja\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from my_table]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <variable name="retval_main" class="java.lang.String" calculation="System"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="43" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <summary>
        <band height="226" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="31" y="173" width="100" height="20" uuid="4e5ed8fa-e4f6-42bc-8651-6888d79f01b5"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{retval_main}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="15" y="16" width="200" height="100" uuid="2bd63504-b57e-4561-b527-62f6ffe46a30"/>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <returnValue subreportVariable="retval_sub" toVariable="retval_main"/>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "testing_ret_val_subreport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Sub Report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="testing_ret_val_subreport1" language="groovy" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="822d1131-8494-45f3-a9ab-39fc9a05072f">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select id from my_table]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <variable name="retval_sub" class="java.lang.String">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA["Hai"]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <detail>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="107" y="17" width="100" height="20" uuid="f8d1612a-06be-4082-b915-0df82b3faa42"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{retval_sub}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Please suggest

Comment: `but it is not working i kept calculation type as System and Nothing also but it is not working for both.` - What does it mean? What did you get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returned value from subeport to main report is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384421/returned-value-from-subeport-to-main-report-is-null) & [How can I pass sub-report value to main-report?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14492956/876298)

Answer (score 0):

`<subreport>
                <reportElement x="-6" y="0" width="570" height="59" uuid="ac54a12b-8022-49a1-bc90-90cff664e3a1"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("footer")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["footer.jrxml"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>`

add this to your code, it will work